# WixSharp installer Registry Creation

Tags: c#, wix, wixsharp

There are several posts regarding the creation of registry keys. However, i am trying to create the registry entries during radiobutton clicks.

I get the error message "Requested registry access is not allowed" when i try to access registry.

I tried with

```
project.InstallPrivileges = InstallPrivileges.elevated;
project.InstallScope = InstallScope.perMachine;
```

To have the admin privileges and also added the application manifest file and configured,

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

I noticed the application(Project) exe has the admin access now and wix installer doesn't have it.

Also, If i create the registries during build there is no issues. However, when user clicks on radio button on the UI, it doesnt seem to have admin rights

```
 var project = new Project("iaAgent",
        new Dir(@"%ProgramFiles%\Test",
        new DirFiles(@"C:\Test\Test\Test\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\win-x64\*.*")));
    project.InstallPrivileges = InstallPrivileges.elevated;
    project.InstallScope = InstallScope.perMachine;
    InjectProductActivationDialog(project);
    Compiler.PreserveTempFiles = true;

    //Reg Entries
    Compiler.BuildMsi(project);
```

Please help me to gain the admin access(UAC) screen whenever user executes the setup. Or is there any custom action to create the registry keys

Comment: How your radio buttons are implemented? Does them implemented as the part of MSI UI or as inside of bootstrapper?

Comment: It's implemented as part of MSI UI

Comment: You should use  ManagedProject.RegValues values to set your properties if you need to access elevated registry branches